# Search filter by first and last name in React not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs, search, filter, react-hooks

I'm building a simple dynamic search filter that DOES filter out data but not exactly by first and last name. I need it to be exactly by first and last name. For example, if I type 'to', and first name like 'tom' or last name like 'tollison'.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar"
import axios from "axios"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState(null)
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("")
 
 useEffect(() => {
   const fetchStudents = async () => {
     const result = await axios("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students")
     setStudents(result.data.students)
   }
   fetchStudents()
 }, [])



  const convertStudentGrades = (grades) =>
    grades.map((grade) => parseInt(grade))

  const getStudentAverage = (grades) =>
    grades.reduce((sum, elem) => sum + elem, 0) / grades.length

  const capitalizeFullName = (first, last) => (
    <span>{`${first.toUpperCase()} ${last.toUpperCase()}`}</span>
  )


  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <input type="text" value={searchTerm} onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} placeholder="Search..." />
    
     
        {students && students.filter(student => {
         if (searchTerm == "") {
            return student  
         } else if (student.firstName[0].includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || student.lastName.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
           return student
         }
        }).map(student => (
          <div className='row' key={student.id}>
            <div className='student-image'>
              <img src={student.pic} alt='' />
            </div>

            <div className='student-info'>
              <h1>
                <span>
                  {capitalizeFullName(student.firstName, student.lastName)}
                </span>
              </h1>
              <p>Email: {student.email}</p>
              <p>Company: {student.company}</p>
              <p>Skill: {student.skill}</p>
              <p>
                Average:{" "}
                {getStudentAverage(convertStudentGrades(student.grades))}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I would also like to move that ugly filter method in JSX to a method to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `startsWith` instead of `contains`.

```
const filteredStudent = () => {
    return students && searchTerm !== "" ? students.filter(student => student.firstName[0].startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || student.lastName.startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) : students;
}

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <input type="text" value={searchTerm} onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} placeholder="Search..." />
    
     
        {filteredStudent().map(student => (
          <div className='row' key={student.id}>
            <div className='student-image'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was fetching my data from mongo db. I had my contacts stored with firstName and lastName fields. In my react-table component I would fetch my data and call it "contacts"

I then passed my contacts to my react-table like this below

```
 <Fragment>
                <Card>
                <AdvanceTableWrapper
                  columns={columns}
                  data={contacts} // <--- here is my redux data 
                  sortable
                  pagination
                  perPage={50}
                  selection
                  selectionColumnWidth={25}
                  selectionCallback={selectionCallback}
                  
                >
                  <Row className="flex-start-center mb-3 ml-1">
                    <Col>
                      <AdvanceTableSearchBox table/>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                 
                  <AdvanceTable
                    table
                    headerClassName="bg-200 text-900 font-weight-bold text-nowrap align-middle"
                    rowClassName="btn-reveal-trigger border-top border-200 align-middle white-space-nowrap"
                    tableProps={{
                      striped: true,
                      className: 'fs--1 font-weight-bold overflow-hidden'
                    }}
                  />
                  <div className="mt-3 mb-2 pr-2 pl-3 ">
                    <AdvanceTableFooter
                      rowCount={contacts?.length} // <-- again my redux data
                      table
                      rowInfo
                      navButtons
                      rowsPerPageSelection
                    />
                  </div>
                </AdvanceTableWrapper>
                
                </Card>
                </Fragment>
```

In order to search two columns at once I just added a new property to the object like so

```
const contacts = useSelector((state) => state.contacts)


const contactsTwo = contacts?.map((el) => { return {...el, name: el.firstName + " " + el.lastName }})

//
```

Now I just add a new column and use "d-none" to hide it

```
 const columns = [
    
    {
        accessor: 'firstName',
        Header: 'First Name',
        Cell: firstNameFormatter
    },
    {
        accessor: 'lastName',
        Header: 'Last Name',
        Cell: lastNameFormatter
    },
    {
      accessor: 'name',
      headerProps: {
        className: "d-none"
      },
      cellProps: {
        className: 'd-none',
    }
  },

];
```

Now when I search for "Jane Doe" it shows everything, where as before If I put a space after a name my results would disappear.